# Does Magento store copies of the Email messages sent through the CONTACT US page? Is it possible to retrieve them?

Tags: contact-us, contact-form

I made a big mistake by not changing the "Send Emails To" Email address in:

> SYSTEM - CONFIGURATION - GENERAL - CONTACTS - Email Options

The Email address in there was **"hello@example.com"** this whole time and so the customers who filled out the CONTACT US form on the

> www.mywebsitte.com/contacts

page sent that message to hello@example.com instead of our own Email address. I am not even sure if the hello@example.com Email address exists? Are there copies of the messages that are actually SENT by the Magento system through this Contact Us page kept anywhere? Can they be retrieved? It's important for us to get them back if possible.

I checked the default Email address on our domain but did not find copies of messages there.

**EDITED 03-09-2017:**

I sent a test message from my personal Email to "hello@example.com" yesterday and just now the Email returned with "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender".

Your message for hello@example.com from 2017/03/08 could not be delivered. 
It's attached below.

### Reason:

4.4.0 smtp; 93.184.216.34: Timeout while connecting. 
Persistent Transient Failure - Other or undefined network or routing status

So this would indicate this Email address does not exist at all and the Emails were being returned to sender....Any idea where they were returned to? Maybe I can still look for them.

Answer (score 1):

Using Contact Us form, magento will not store copies of the Email messages.

Instead if your server is configured properly, then you may get return mails for unable to send mail to sender in your webmail